# Problem in booting an u-boot image for raspberry pi 2 on QEMU

Tags: pi-2, qemu, u-boot

Needed some help in running u-boot on qemu emulating Raspberry pi 2.
I came across qemu supporting emulation of Raspbeerry pi 2 (raspi2 machine in qemu).
I thought of giving it a try by running u-boot compiled for Raspberry pi 2.
I used the config "rpi_2_defconfig" to build u-boot.

following is the command I used to invoke QEMU
qemu-system-arm -M raspi2 -kernel u-boot

i see the following message on the serial console of qemu

```
U-Boot 2017.03-01088-gd0ffda8-dirty (Apr 27 2017 - 09:21:24 +0530)

DRAM: 960 MiB
RPI 2 Model B (0xa21041)
MMC: bcm2835_sdhci: 0
```

And it never goes past this point and I never get the u-boot console.

I tried debugging through gdb.

this is the back trace of the stack

```
#0 timer_get_us () at lib/time.c:124
#1 0x3bf643d4 in bcm2835_sdhci_raw_writel (reg=44, val=16777216, host=0x3bb3d3e8) at drivers/mmc/bcm2835_sdhci.c:74
#2 bcm2835_sdhci_writeb (host=0x3bb3d3e8, val=<optimized out>, reg=<optimized out>) at drivers/mmc/bcm2835_sdhci.c:117
#3 0x3bf63270 in sdhci_writeb (reg=47, val=val@entry=1 '\001', host=host@entry=0x3bb3d3e8) at include/sdhci.h:285
#4 sdhci_reset (host=host@entry=0x3bb3d3e8, mask=mask@entry=1 '\001') at drivers/mmc/sdhci.c:29
#5 0x3bf63308 in sdhci_init (mmc=0x3bb3d460) at drivers/mmc/sdhci.c:481
#6 0x3bf62b48 in mmc_start_init (mmc=0x3bb3d460) at drivers/mmc/mmc.c:1673
#7 0x3bf62d90 in mmc_init (mmc=mmc@entry=0x3bb3d460) at drivers/mmc/mmc.c:1746
#8 0x3bf610b4 in mmc_get_dev (dev=<optimized out>, descp=0x3bb38ccc) at drivers/mmc/mmc_legacy.c:221
#9 0x3bf602c8 in blk_get_devnum_by_typename (if_typename=if_typename@entry=0x3bf89bc5 "mmc", devnum=devnum@entry=0)
at drivers/block/blk_legacy.c:205
#10 0x3bf5ce48 in get_dev_hwpart (hwpart=0, dev=0, ifname=0x3bf89bc5 "mmc") at disk/part.c:48
#11 blk_get_device_by_str (ifname=ifname@entry=0x3bf89bc5 "mmc", dev_hwpart_str=dev_hwpart_str@entry=0x3bb3d5c0 "0",
dev_desc=0x3bb38dc4, dev_desc@entry=0x3bf5cf78 <blk_get_device_part_str+176>) at disk/part.c:367
#12 0x3bf5cf78 in blk_get_device_part_str (ifname=ifname@entry=0x3bf89bc5 "mmc",
dev_part_str=dev_part_str@entry=0x3bf854c1 "0:1", dev_desc=0x3bf5cf78 <blk_get_device_part_str+176>,
dev_desc@entry=0x3bb38dbc, info=0x3bb38dc8, info@entry=0x3bb38dc0, allow_whole_dev=allow_whole_dev@entry=1)
at disk/part.c:475
#13 0x3bf51db4 in env_relocate_spec () at common/env_fat.c:85
#14 0x3bf578a0 in env_relocate () at common/env_common.c:268
#15 0x3bf501c4 in initr_env () at common/board_r.c:479
#16 0x3bf71144 in initcall_run_list (init_sequence=init_sequence@entry=0x3bf8ecd8) at lib/initcall.c:31
#17 0x3bf50314 in board_init_r (new_gd=<optimized out>, dest_addr=<optimized out>) at common/board_r.c:947
#18 0x3bf41710 in _main () at arch/arm/lib/crt0.S:153
#19 0x3bf41710 in _main () at arch/arm/lib/crt0.S:153
```

Could somebody help me in further debugging?
QEMU version: 2.8

Regards.

Comment: Did you got any solution for this ?

Comment: @RahulAN I was running qemu in a Linux guest machine. Not sure what the issue was. I tried running the same in a windows host machine and things came up fine.

Comment: Well i am also using linux as host.
but that's weird why it is hanging up there.

Comment: @RahulAN are you seeing similar issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@pradeepmcp 
i was facing same issue , but now it got fixed 
https://plus.google.com/u/0/+StephenWarren/posts/G1sJ1RD4qPr?cfem=1

this helped me .. there is an issue with qemu and u-boot for rpi2 Machine.
but https://github.com/0xabu/qemu will work though :)

with the above qemu i am able to get u-boot working.